# how to connect to another user in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I need to connect from user to another user in pl/sql noting that I don't have DBA privilege.

Can you give me the command for connection between two users?

Comment: Do you really need to connect as a different user? Or just access to another schema's objects (such as tables)?

Comment: i need to connect as new user that i have his user_name and password.to use tables and procedures....... etc

Comment: Then @PetrPriby gave you the answer - just grant privileges to your user on the other schema objects and reference them as `<other_schema>.<object>`

Comment: but I don't have DBA privilege.

Comment: Do you have another way to work the system security to protect the database in pl/sql program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new connection, just add the other user_name to his/her tables and procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM user_name.his_table WHERE ...;
```

If you get an error message `ORA-00942: table or view does not exists`, then you log in as new user and set the access privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT ON his_table TO <old_user>;
```

Comment: the old user has no privilege. i need to jump to another user to use his tables and procedures ... etc
is a connection command to make this? like is sql connect user_name/password;

Comment: SQL*Plus is a client programm that connects to the database. It can disconnect and reconnect as another user. PL/SQL runs **in** the database. Once you're connected as user a, you cannot connect as another user b from within PL/SQL.

Comment: .. but jumping to another user is really not neccessary. You have the password of the other user, don't you?

Comment: yes,i have a password , if you please can you tell me how to jump to another user?

Comment: You can jump from SQL*Plus, but not from PL/SQL. If you have the password, connect as the other user and run the `GRANT` statement. Do you need help with the GRANT?

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL has no command for changing connection. If you need some specific privileges you have to grant them.